# How to delete the first BoundingBox from the image after using regionprops in Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I want to make all of the pixels within the area of the first bounding box zero after using regionprops function in Matlab

Answer (score 1):

OK, after the OP has edited the Q: let's say you have a (grayscale) image `im`, it'll make a copy of it in `im1` and nullify all pixels in the copy in the first bounding box

```
im1 =im;
STATS = regionprops(im);
bb = STATS(1).BoundingBox;
bb=floor(bb); %need to have integers in indices
im1(bb(1):bb(1)+bb(2),bb(3):bb(3)+bb(4))=0;
```

Comment: thank you for your response, but I want to display the first BoundingBox only, and remove the unwanted areas which are in this case the other BoundingBox(s)

Comment: @malmo that's why you have that (1) in `STATS(1)`

Comment: there was an extra paren there, sorry

Comment: It is common to add some explanatory text to your answer. This helps the audience to understand what you are doing and prevents unnecessary downvotes due to lack of context.

Comment: @malmo - try again with this new code, there was a typo, that I fixed and unnecessary 'FaceColor' property. I tested the code and it worked

Comment: it didn't work for I 've tried the new code its gives me a white rectangle

Comment: @malmo Perhaps it would be helpful if you told us *exactly* the results you desire. Obviously our interpretation of "keep the first BoundingBox only" is different than yours. `STATS(1).BoundingBox` returns the rectangle definition for the first bounding box *only*. If this isn't what you want, you'll need to clarify.

Comment: @beaker actually I want to remove the first BoundingBox  from the image

Comment: @malmo Your requirements are still ambiguous. Do you want to make all of the pixels within the area of the bounding box zero? Do you wish to make a new image containing only the pixels with the area of the bounding box? Something else? Please edit your question and clarify precisely what you want, preferably with images and the code you've tried.

Comment: @beaker that exactly what I want  to make all of the pixels within the area of the first bounding box zero

Comment: @malmo How is that the same as "keep only the first BoundingBox"? Please edit your question appropriately.

Comment: @malmo check the new answer for your new question

Comment: @HennadiiMadan  I ve just tried it , I get this error "Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals"